# Popup chart in vb.net on mouse over

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm looking to simulate the functionality of FINVIZ.COM where, when you hover over a value (the Ticker simbol in their case) a chart pops up.

Is this possible to do it in asp.net? Maybe be using an AJAX control?

Any hints will be apprecaited

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Download the demo and browse through. You will find examples of doing exactly what you want.

Read more about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Comment: The link that you provided provides a basic instructions on how to created a chart in ASP.NET. I'm okay with that, I need to be able to pop up a chart when hovering over a GridView, for example.

Comment: @Selrac ooops I gave the wrong link. Sorry. Here is the correct link: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Comment: Again, this is a very good source on how to create charts, but I don't think it is getting what I'm looking for. The only section that I've found usefull from the chart demos is the section 'drill down and preview' which show a popup chart when hovering another chart, but the code behind is not very explicit for what I want :-(

Comment: @Selrac This *does* get you what you are looking for. Have you opened up the code in `tooltipdrilldown.aspx` and `TooltipDrillDown.aspx.cs` files? Please go through the code and try to understand how it has been implemented. You will get the idea. After all as per your question, you wanted a *hint* (*any hints will be appreciated*), didn't you?

Comment: Thanks abhitalks, I'll experiment with the tooltips. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @Selrac Thanks for accepting. Please note that this is actually very simple. The ASP.Net charting will generate a chart as an image. And you can have an `img` tag inside a `div` on your page and point the `src` attribute of the `img` to an aspx page which spews out the chart. Now all that remains is to show/hide that div on hover using javascript and change the `src` to point to that page with a querystring variable (to identify which chart to show in code-behind).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the help from another stackoverflow page ([jQuery popup div in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526113/jquery-popup-div-in-gridview))

Here is my code example in case it helps anyone:

Style

```
     .HoverDesc{
        Position:relative;
    }

    .HoverDesc Strong{
        display:block;
        line-height:20px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .HoverDesc p{
        z-index:5;
        display:none;
        padding:10px;
        margin:0;
        background:#ccc;
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:0;            
    }
```

jQuery Include

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.HoverDesc').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('p').show(200);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('p').hide(100);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

ASPX GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="Table0" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ASL" HeaderText="SL" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="HoverDesc">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Height="20px" src="Images/Icons/iGreen.png" />
                    <p>
                        <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="141px">
                            <Series>
                                <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" XValueMember="date" YValueMembers="Value">
                                </asp:Series>
                            </Series>
                            <ChartAreas>
                                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                            </ChartAreas>
                        </asp:Chart>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have to figure out how to link the row information to the query now, so that the chart displayed is relevant to the row I'm hovering, but that is another story...