# Popup chart not working inside Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have successfully built a popup chart which is displayed when hovering over an image located in a GridView. The problem is that if I put the Gridview inside an UpdatePanel the popup does not display once the page updates after changing selection on a dropdown located in the page.

See code example below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:GridView ID="Table0" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL">
    ....
  </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have the full code in the following two pages:

- [Popup chart in vb.net on mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266983/popup-chart-in-vb-net-on-mouse-over/19267152#comment28530994_19267152)
- [Pop up chart from GridView to display data based on row reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277384/pop-up-chart-from-gridview-to-display-data-based-on-row-reference/19298690#19298690)

I tried adding the following code following another website (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx)

```
    //On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(jQuery(document).ready(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
        $('.HoverDesc').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('p').show(200);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('p').hide(100);
        });
            }
        }));
    };
```

But I'm getting an error message:

Error: Unable to get value of the property 'panelsToUpdate': object is null or undefined

I tried also the following, which causes no error, but it does not seem to work:

```
    //On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    $('.HoverDesc').hover(function () {
                        $(this).find('p').show(200);
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).find('p').hide(100);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, I've managed to resolve the problem with the help of this page:

http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/02/24/jQuery-document-ready-and-ASP-NET-Ajax-asynchronous-postback.aspx

The code is as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
            alertTest();
        }
    }

    function alertTest() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('.HoverDesc').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('p').show(200);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('p').hide(100);
            });
        });
    }

    alertTest();   

</script>
```